# select index value from groupby on a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'place'     : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
               'population': [10 , 20, 30, 15, 25, 35],
               'region': ['I', 'II', 'III', 'I', 'II', 'III']})
```

And it looks like this:

```
      place  population region
0     A          10      I
1     B          20     II
2     C          30    III
3     D          15      I
4     E          25     II
5     F          35    III
```

I would like to select the place with the smallest population from the region with the highest population.

```
df.groupby('region').population.sum()
```

Returns:

```
region
I      25
II     45
III    65
Name: population, dtype: int64
```

But I have no clue how to proceed from here (using .groupby / .loc / .iloc)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add a column for region population:

```
df['region_pop'] = df.groupby('region')['population'].transform(sum)
```

Then sort your dataframe and extract the first row:

```
res = df.sort_values(['region_pop', 'population'], ascending=[False, True])\
        .head(1)
```

Result:

```
  place  population region  region_pop
2     C          30    III          65
```

Comment: I believe this would be faster than my solution. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks, nice! Is there a way to do it in one line of code (with method chaining)?

Comment: @Rene, Probably, but it'll be an unreadable mess I would have difficulty understanding.

Comment: df.assign(region_population = df.groupby('region')['population'].transform(sum)).sort_values(['region_population', 'population'], ascending=[False, True]).iloc[0].place

Comment: @Rene, Yep, that would be the one-liner. But don't let it make you believe it's more efficient. You are just moving an explicit series definition to `pd.DataFrame.assign`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the `region` with highest `population`. Then `groupby` `place` to the subset of data with that region and find the place with lowest `population`. (Assuming place would be repetitive in real data)

```
high_reg = df.groupby('region')['population'].sum().reset_index(name='count').sort_values('count').iloc[-1]['region']
df.loc[df['region']==high_reg].groupby('place')['population'].sum().reset_index(name='count').sort_values('count').iloc[0]['place']
```

Output:

```
'C'
```